# Yii2 как в ActiveDataProvider добавить атрибут?

Tags: php, yii2, gridview

Добрый день,

```
     $query = Bg_seminar::find()->joinWith ('participant')->groupBy('seminar_id');
 $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['seminar_id'=>SORT_DESC]],
        ]);
 GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider, ...
...
```

как в `$dataProvider` добавить атрибуты поверх тех, которые автоматом добавляют поля таблицы Bg_seminar ? Почему если сделать вложенный SELECT в SELECT'e,то поля вложенного не добавляются как атрибуты?

Comment: Можете более детально обьяснить свой вопрос? что вам необходимо дабавить?